# Are there any projects which add additional exit points to the Tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

[Snowflake](https://web.archive.org/web/20230212183314/https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/anti-censorship/pluggable-transports/snowflake/-/wikis/Technical%20Overview) is a known project, which adds some entry points to the Tor network.

Are there also projects, that add additional exit points to the Tor network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new entry, middle and exit points to the Tor network, by Tor network. But, to do it on this way, are public.

See follow Tor relay guide:

- https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/wikis/TorRelayGuide

Comment: but this is a Tor project itself - see the question :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, it is technically **impossible** to *add additional exit points to tor* - because of how it's built. Snowflake is just turning a browser into the proxy for tor, but it does **not** add any exit nodes which are the only exit points